# Filebeat is not forwarding logs

Tags: docker, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I followed all the steps mentioned here readthedocs but my filebeat is not sending logs to the url http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty.

my filebeat.yml file is - https://ghostbin.com/paste/rrjeh

I didn't config any logstash file as mentioned.

my registry file is filling after starting of filebeat and filebeat log (syslog) is showing no error regarding filebeat

Answer (score 2):

In the bottom of `/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml` you should see a "logging" section.  You will need to uncomment it and fill in the appropriate fields for you.  Maybe some logging output would be helpful in formulating your question.

```
logging:
  to_files: true
  files:
    path: /var/log/filebeat
    name: filebeat.log
    rotateeverybytes: 10485760 # = 10MB
    keepfiles: 7
  level: debug
```

Answer (score 1):

I have filebeat version  5.0.0 installed on my machine. For deugging and logging purposes, below configurations in the logging section of filebeat.yml file helped me :

```
logging.level: debug
logging.to_files: true
logging.to_syslog: false
logging.files:
path: /var/log/mybeat
name: mybeat.log
keepfiles: 7
```

source- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-logging.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change filebeat's log level to 'info' to see it attempt to connect to logstash.

Your readthedocs link is currently broken, but if you haven't configured logstash to use a filebeat input on port 5044 and created a proper certificate for it, this will definitely not send logs as filebeat will just get a refused connection.

If you don't want to do any parsing with logstash, you could just use the elasticsearch output from filebeat and skip logstash all together.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal,

you said, "i didn't config any logstash"... you specified a port "5044" moreover a certificate and furthermore no logstash configuration, you need in conf logstash

```
input{
   beat{
      port:5044
       }
      }
```

If you have no informations to add it is better to send directly to ES...